# php and webservices

Tags: php, web-services

I have a wsdl file and i am trying to call it from a php class. I am using the following code:

```
<?php
```

include ("dbconn.php");

class dataclass
{

```
function getCountries()
{
    $connection = new dbconn();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblcountries";

    $dataset = $connection -> connectSql($sql);

    return $dataset;
}

function getTest()
{
    $connection = new dbconn();

    $sql = mysql_query('CALL sp_getTest');

    $dataset =  $connection -> connectSql($sql);

    return $dataset;
}


##-------------------------------------------CUSTOMER METHODS-------------------------------------------
function registerCustomer($username,$name,$surname,$password,$email,$country,$tel)
{
    $connection = new dbconn();

    $sql="INSERT INTO tblcustomer (customer_username, customer_password, customer_name, customer_surname,
        customer_email, customer_country, customer_tel) 
        VALUES('$username','$name','$surname','$password','$email','$country','$tel')";

    $dataset = $connection -> connectSql($sql);

}



ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
// start the SOAP server - point to the wsdl file
$webservice = new SoapServer("http://localhost/dataobjects/myWebservice.wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

// publish methods
$webservice->addFunction("getCountries");
$webservice->addFunction("registerCustomer");
// publish
$webservice->handle();
```

}
?>

It is all the time giving me a problem with `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");`

The error is:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\Program Files\xampplite\htdocs\dataobjects\dataClass.php on line 47`

Comment: can you please post dataClass.php ? Your Source code looks ok.

Comment: So what do you have on and around line 47? Because this ini_set is certainly now giving that error, it must be something before it.

Comment: Yes, please give a look at line 47. In fact, this should be re-tagged "line 47".

Comment: line 47: is the ini_set(...

Before the ini_set(... there are functions such as register and get countries nothing more.  they work fine if connected to the webpage eliminating the webservice.

tried also to remove the 0 between "" but still with same problem

Comment: Can you post the few lines before line 47?  Hit "edit".  It's 4 spaces indent for code.

Comment: function registerCustomer($username,$name,$surname,$password,$email,$country,$tel)
 {
  $connection = new dbconn();
  
  $sql="INSERT INTO tblcustomer (customer_username, customer_password, customer_name, customer_surname,
   customer_email, customer_country, customer_tel) 
   VALUES('$username','$name','$surname','$password','$email','$country','$tel')";
  
  $dataset = $connection -> connectSql($sql);
 
 }
  
 // uncache otherwise the client might cache the wsdl
 ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

Comment: i edited it in the problem. pasted all dataclass for you to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because you have ini_set() call in the body of your class.  Put it at the top of the file or in the constructor if you have one.

```
class dataClass
{
    function registerCustomer()
    {
       // some stuff
    }

    ini_set(/*args*/); // it's illegal to put instructions in the body of the class
}
```

Now I see the whole thing.  You probably want to close the class with a closing backet before line 47.

Answer (score 0):

You let the parser think "0" is a string, and not a number, please remove the quotes!

**Edit 1** If that wouldn't work, your error must be before that line, please post the full code for review.

**Edit 2** The code you provided was running inside the class, you miss a bracket before the line with ini_set.

Answer (score 0):

Move the last } in front of ini_set(...)

By the way, you said you want to call a web service, but you are creating a server which may be called by others.

To **call** a web service, try something like this:

```
try{
    $client = new SoapClient($service, array('location' =>"http://example.org/myWebService"));
    $parameter1 = new myWebServiceParameter();
    $result = $client->myWebServiceFunction($parameter1);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle errors
}
```

myWebServiceParameter must be any class with a member variable foreach WSDL message attribute of the same name.
And myWebServiceFunction is the name of the web service method.